# How do open, injective functions have continuous inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How do we prove, if a complex/real function is injective and open then its inverse is continuous?

If a function is open, doesn't it necessarily have a continuous inverse by definition? Where do we use injectivity?

Moreover, can I conclude, if an open function has a continuous inverse, so it is a bijection?

Comment: Inverse is well-defined only for injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your function is called $f$. There is an inverse (not necessarily continuous) function $f^{-1}$ pecicely because $f$ is injective. For continuity, recall that a function $g$ is continuous if the inverse image of open sets ($g^{-1}(U)$) are open. But the inverse image of open sets over the inverse function ($(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)$) is the same as direct images of open sets over the original function ($f(U)$). They are open because the function is open. Therefore the inverse is continuous.

Comment: But if $f$ is injective but not surjective, then its inverse is a partial function, right?

Comment: @Serpenche Yes. An injective function is only bijective on its image. So you have to restrict the codomain to just be the range of $f$ for this to work.